# PayPal IPN does not fire when users cancel PreApproval Apdaptive Payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I use Paypal IPN to update order status when users confirmed or canceled a payment with PreApproval Adaptive Payments.

IPN fires when an order confirmed and completed. But when users go to their Paypal dashboard and cancel the Pre-Approval, nothing happens.

Do you guys have any experience about this case?

Thank you very much for looking at.

Answer (score 1):

With Adaptive Payments there are actually two IPNs that could trigger.  One is app specific, and this would be set using the IpnNotificationUrl parameter in the Pay request.  The other would be transaction specific and would trigger based on the IPN settings in the receiver profile.

It sounds like you could be expecting to see app specific IPNs at your PayPal profile listener..??

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Thank you for the answer. Yes, I put the link of my website to my PayPal profile and expect that link to be called by IPN when someone cancels the PreApproval Agreement.

Comment: You'll want to test to confirm, but I'm pretty sure that type of an IPN would be sent to the app specific listener, so that would have to be setup in the IpnNotificationUrl parameter of your Adaptive requests.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I added the ipnNotificationUrl to the requests and wait for the result.